# Migration with duplicate entry error

Tags: 8, migrations

I'm running migration in Drupal 8, but got a duplicate error below.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '10b1b105-355b-3c77-8880-a0c247f826f3' for key 'node_field__uuid__value': INSERT INTO     [error]
{node} (vid, type, uuid, langcode) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3); Array
```

My question, is there any configuration or a migration plugin that I have to specify in my migration config yml file to check for existing record and update if exists, if not exists then create a new record?

I'm using migration_plus module.

Comment: Not enough information here - how would you get duplicate UUID values? Is this just a field or core generated UUID data?

Comment: It's a core UUID generated data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer from someone on Facebook group (Drupal support group)
The answer is to add " --update" argument to the migration command, it will check for existing record and update it, or create new record if not exists.